# Name for Objects on a Map

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm trying to write up a specification for a bit of programming, but I'm at a loss on how to actually describe what the, well, *things* on the map are.

For context, this is a user-generated map that has the ability to have markers (points with icons), routes (lines defined by roads), paths (lines defined as-the-crow-flies), and shapes (circles and polygons).

So, my question is, **is there a universal word or term to describe points, lines, *and* shapes on a map?**

Comment: I was hoping that [this page of map terminology](http://www.worldatlas.com/mapterms.htm) might help. Alas, no.

Comment: Ink?  Take the points, lines and shapes off a map and what's going to be left?  The fold lines?  Could you distinguish what you're including and excluding here a little more exactly please.

Comment: Instinct is to use "markup", but I'm a developer.

Comment: "Chart-junk" :-P

Comment: @CandiedOrange It's a generated Google Map. Google allows a lot more than I'm offering, but even they don't define everything under an umbrella term. Correction: I believe they actually call them "objects," but I'm afraid that's too broad for the average user, as they won't automatically associate the word with "class."

Comment: @cwallenpoole Markup isn't a bad idea. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: In the GIS field these are generally referred to as ['features'](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/GISDictionary/term/feature).

Comment: @ChrisR Can you post that as an answer?

Comment: In such map application context, it may be refered as the "user layer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cartography any object or representation on a map is referred to as a [feature](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/GISDictionary/term/feature). You can be more specific about what feature by adding geometric terms (point, line, polygon) or any number of things before the word feature.

[image]

Comment: The irony is when you style a Google Map, everything is a "feature." I guess I was just staring at it for too long.

Comment: I do it all the time :)